# Hide referral information when my site users click on external links

Tags: security, http, web, proxy, referrer

I apologize for my lack of knowledge on how the intricacies of the web work ahead of time.

I run a fairly large deal site (lets call it dealsite.com) and we send a lot of traffic to Amazon.com. Is there anyway for me to hide from Amazon that the users are are coming from dealsite.com? I do not want Amazon to know that we (dealsite.com) are the ones sending the traffic.

Maybe strip certain cookies?
Send outbound traffic through a proxy?

I am not doing anything illegal and these are real users not bots.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the users on dealsite.com are redirected to Amazon ?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `noreferrer` tag on your links, you can prevent Amazon from learning their traffic is coming from your site, and you don't need to set up a proxy, vpn, or cookie redirects.

HTTP generally sends the referring page along with its request for the new page as part of the [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) section of the request header, and that's how sites track where their visitors come from. So for example, a user would click through to Amazon.com from Dealsite.com, and the request would include an `HTTP referer` telling Amazon.com that the user was linked from Dealsite.com.

To prevent web sites like Amazon from learning that their traffic came from your site, prevent your links from sending the `HTTP referer`. In HTML5, [just add `rel="noreferrer"` to your links](http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tags/fl/rel-noreferrer.htm), and then referral information will not be sent to the site that was linked. The `noreferrer` link type is only suppported in new browsers, so I suggest using the [knu's noreferrer polyfill](https://github.com/knu/noreferrer) to make sure it works on older browsers too.

So far this will prevent referrer information from being sent from 99.9% of your users -  the only users that will send referral information will be users that are **both** using old browsers **and** have JavaScript disabled. To make it 100%, you could require users have JavaScript enabled to be able to click on those particular links.

Comment: you killed it! Thanks man. My only concern is that, having a blank HTTP referer will send off a flag with Amazon? Is there a way I could change the HTTP referer to say "google.com" for example? The more organic the traffic looks to Amazon the better. Do you imagine having a blank referer would not be significant to Amazon?

Comment: @cgauss Lots of natural traffic doesn't have any referrer either, so no flag will be set off at Amazon. Direct Traffic (no referrer) is common, and here is an [article that gives you more details on what it means](http://www.lizlockard.com/analytics-direct-traffic/). From the article: all of the following are natural sources of traffic that come with no referrer: 1. Your visitor typed your website address directly into the browser. 2. Your visitor clicked a link inside an email. 3. Your visitor clicked on a shortened URL (sometimes) 4. Your visitor has your site bookmarked, etc.

Comment: @cgauss So to Amazon, it just looks like a lot of people bookmarked their pages, or followed from emails or Skype messages, or used link shorteners, or other ways that can't be tracked (that don't send referrer info).

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, Is it possible to be anonymous from Amazon bots while sending users to Amazon from my website just by setting 'noreferrer' in <a> tag?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is not the *thorough* idea you're looking for. I ran out of space in the comments so posted it as an answer. A couple of possible solutions come to my mind.

**Proxy servers:** Multiple distributed proxy servers to be specific. You can round robin your users through these servers and and hit Amazon so that the inbound traffic to Amazon from dualist.com keeps *revolving*. Disadvantage is that this will be slow depending on where the proxy server resides. So not the most ideal solution for an Ecommerce site but it works. And the major advantage is that implementation will be very simple.

**VPN tunneling:** Extremely similar to proxy server. VPN tunnel to another server and send redirect to Amazon from there. You'll get a new (non dealsite.com) IP from the VPN server of this network and your original IP will be masked

**Redirects from user (Still in works)** For this one I was thinking of if you could store the info you need from dealsite.com in a cookie and then instruct the host to redirect to Amazon by itself. *Hence the inbound traffic to Amazon will be from the users IP and not dealsite.coms*. If you need to get back to the dealsite session from Amazon, you could use the previously saved cookie to do so.

Ill add to this answer if I find something better.

**Edit 1** A few hours more hours researching brought me to the [Tor project](https://www.torproject.org/). This might be useful but be wary, Many security experts advise against using Tor. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/how-much-can-i-trust-tor)

Comment: @SheyasChavan I appreciate the information! I will upvote your answer here in a couple of hours. Could you point me to any articles so I can learn how to send my traffic through the Proxy Servers or VPN Tunnel? Thank you again!

Comment: You can get the information on proxy pretty much anywhere. [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/the-basics-of-using-a-proxy-server-for-privacy-and-security/) covers the basics well. Thats a good start. As far as VPN Tunnelling goes [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/vpn-tunnel-set/) covers the basics. This [CISCO paper](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/app_notes/rv0xx_g2gvpn_an_OL-26286.pdf) is also useful. And as far as the TOR project goes. The link in the answer covers everything there is to know about it.

Comment: @cgauss As far as I understand, you are trying to make it so when you post links to `Amazon.com` from `Dealsite.com`, Amazon won't know that those users are being referred to them by `Dealsite.com`, correct? A proxy may be overkill for this, and VPN/Tor will not work unless your site users set up VPN/Tor software on their computers (i.e. it's a no-go). See if my answer about stripping referrer information is good enough for your use case.